# how to zoom out page in mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have created a fluid webpage, i used % width to make it adjust to every resolution.

But the problem is in mobile device the page layout breaks. I want to zoom out the page for mobile device so the page fits in small width and user can zoom in to enlarge the page.

I tried the below meta tag. But the problem is here user can't zoom in. `user-scalable=yes` and `initial-scale=0.25` is not working together.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=0.25" />
```

Comment: In your example user-scalable = no.

Comment: I want to make user-scalable=yes but it in that case initial-scale=0.25 is not working

Comment: What about setting width `content="width:1280, user-scalable= yes"` (320 = 1280 * 0.25) for mobile devices?

Comment: @JanneKlouman Klouman I tried what you suggested. But it dosen't work

Comment: try adding minimum-scale

    <meta name="viewport" content=" ... minimum-scale=.25 ...">

Be aware of limitations http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/metaviewport/